# get id by getElementById then set value

Tags: javascript

I wonder why my code doesn't work, btw I was learning javascript object, so ignore the rest of lines of code.

http://jsfiddle.net/aYK8K/

```
var p = document.getElementById(p)
    p.innerHTML("Hmm Hmm Good");
```

Comment: Simply using `console.log()` would have avoided the need for this post.

Comment: @m59 he clearly states he is learning. Linking to a helpful tutorial on debugging would be infinitely more useful than telling someone to use `console.log()`

Comment: @KyleMuir Google is pretty easy to use. Teach (and encourage) a man to fish.

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your fiddle you have

```
<p id="p"></p>
```

So you will want `"p"` not `p`

```
var p = document.getElementById("p"); // note use of string

p.innerHTML = "Hmm Hmm Good";
```

---

To make this less confusing, maybe you should have something like

```
<p id="hello"></p>
```

Then

```
var hello = document.getElementById("hello");
hello.innerHTML = "hello!";
```

This way you avoid brain dizziness by using different names for your elements, IDs, and JavaScript variables.

Comment: Its `p.innerHTML = "Hmm Hmm Good";`

Comment: @ubercooluk what is the different with my code?

Comment: it doesn't work either http://jsfiddle.net/aYK8K/3/

Comment: @user3033162 yes it does. You only have a function defined but nothing is calling it. You just have to call `mango.howSweetAmI();` at the end of your code. Next time paste your actual code in your StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

its `p.innerHTML = "Hmm Hmm Good";`

you should change `p = document.getElementById(p)` to `p = document.getElementById('p')`

I think you have a confusion with jquery syntax,using jquery you can do like

`$('p').html('Hmm Hmm Good');`

Comment: `var p = document.getElementById(p);` isn't going to get him very far

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few things wrong with your solution:

For starters, in your object you need to do the following:

```
var p = document.getElementById('p')
    p.innerHTML = 'Hmm Hmm Good';
```

Next, outside your object you actually need to call the method otherwise nothing will work:

```
mango.howSweetAmI();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/aYK8K/2/

Answer (score 1):

getElementById expects a string

```
var p = document.getElementById('p')
```

innerHTML is not a function

```
p.innerHTML = "Hmm Hmm Good"
```

good luck!